# Relationship based on time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create a relationship between two data frames that are related, but there is no key that creates a relationship. Here is the layout of my problem:
The first data frame that I am using is information about when people entered an amusement park. In this amusement park, people can stay at the park for multiple days. So the structure of this data frame is

| id | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John Smith | 07-01-2020 10:13:24 |
| 1 | John Smith | 07-22-2020 09:47:04 |
| 4 | Jane Doe | 07-22-2020 09:47:04 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 06-13-2020 13:27:53 |
| 3 | Thomas Wallace | 07-08-2020 11:15:28 |

So people may visit the park once, or multiple times (assume that name is a unique identifier for people). For the other data frame, the data is what rides they went on during their time at the park. So the structure of this data frame is

| name | ride | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | Insanity | 07-01-2020 13:53:07 |
| John Smith | Bumper Cars | 07-01-2020 16:37:29 |
| John Smith | Tilt-A-Whirl | 07-02-2020 08:21:18 |
| John Smith | Insanity | 07-22-2020 11:44:32 |
| Jane Doe | Bumper Cars | 06-13-2020 14:14:41 |
| Jane Doe | Teacups | 06-13-2020 17:31:56 |
| Thomas Wallace | Insanity | 07-08-2020 13:20:23 |

With these two data frames, I want to get the id of the visit associated with the rides that they went on during that visit. So the desired output in this example would be

| id | name | ride | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John Smith | Insanity | 07-01-2020 13:53:07 |
| 0 | John Smith | Bumper Cars | 07-01-2020 16:37:29 |
| 0 | John Smith | Tilt-A-Whirl | 07-02-2020 08:21:18 |
| 1 | John Smith | Insanity | 07-22-2020 11:44:32 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | Bumper Cars | 06-13-2020 14:14:41 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | Teacups | 06-13-2020 17:31:56 |
| 3 | Thomas Wallace | Insanity | 07-08-2020 13:20:23 |

The way how I had thought about approaching this problem is by iterating over the visits and then adding the id to the ride if the name matched, the ride occurred during/after the visit, and the time delta is the smallest difference (using a large initial time delta and then updating the smallest different to that difference). If those conditions are not met, then just keep the same value. With this process in mind, here is my thought process in code:

```
rides['min_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(365, unit='day')
rides['id'] = -1
for index, row in visits.iterrows():
    rides['id'], rides['min_diff'] = np.where((rides['name'] == row['name']) & (
                                               rides['date'] >= visits['date']) & (
                                               (rides['date'] - row['date']) < rides['min_diff']),
                                               (row['id'], rides['date'] - row['date']),
                                               (rides['id'], rides['min_diff'))
```

This unfortunately does not execute because of the shapes not matching (as well as trying to assign values across multiple columns, which I am not sure how to do), but this is the general idea. I am not sure how this could be accomplished exactly, so if anyone has a solution, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `apply()` and [`asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asof.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index("date").sort_index() #asof requires a sorted index
df2["id"] = df2.apply(lambda x: df1[df1["Name"]==x["Name"]]["id"].asof(x["date"]), axis=1)

>>> df2
             Name          ride                date  id
0      John Smith      Insanity 2020-07-01 13:53:07   0
1      John Smith   Bumper Cars 2020-07-01 16:37:29   0
2      John Smith  Tilt-A-Whirl 2020-07-02 08:21:18   0
3      John Smith      Insanity 2020-07-22 11:44:32   1
4        Jane Doe   Bumper Cars 2020-06-13 14:14:41   2
5        Jane Doe       Teacups 2020-06-13 17:31:56   2
6  Thomas Wallace      Insanity 2020-07-08 13:20:23   3
```

Comment: This works if there is no overlap in date. Unfortunately, the data that I am working with could easily have the same date and time so I am not sure if this would work

Comment: Then please include a more representative sample where this will not work.

Comment: I have added a row so that this would be a conflict for the solution. I would like to point out that my actual data is much larger than this, so efficiency is important. I cannot include the real data because of confidentiality. I had to come up with a scenario that would apply to my problem and I had to make up fake data, which takes time, so hopefully there is a little more understanding why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** this does what you need. The ids aren't in the order you specified but they do represent visit ids with the logic you requested.

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="right", left_on=['date', 'name'], right_on=['name', 'ride'])[['name_y', 'ride', 'date_y']]
merged['ymd'] = pd.to_datetime(merged.date_y).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
merged['id'] = merged.groupby(['name_y', 'ymd']).ngroup()
merged.drop('ymd', axis=1, inplace=True)
merged.columns = ['name', 'ride', 'date', 'id']
merged.sort_values(by='id', inplace=True)
print(merged)
```

OUT:

```
             name           ride                 date  id
4        Jane Doe   Bumper Cars   06-13-2020 14:14:41   0
5        Jane Doe       Teacups   06-13-2020 17:31:56   0
0      John Smith      Insanity   07-01-2020 13:53:07   1
1      John Smith   Bumper Cars   07-01-2020 16:37:29   1
2      John Smith  Tilt-A-Whirl   07-02-2020 08:21:18   2
3      John Smith      Insanity   07-22-2020 11:44:32   3
6  Thomas Wallace       Insanity  07-08-2020 13:20:23   4
```